# How can I pass the ng-model attribute into a function in ng-class(to set CSS attributes) in a input box

Tags: angularjs

I have used the following code segment where I wanted to change the value of the input box when it is loaded, but it didn't work

test.template.html

```
<div class="col-value">
    <input type="text" class="input-box"  autofocus="autofocus"  ng-blur="saveData(value)" ng-class="getColor(value)" ng-model="value" >%
</div>
```

getColor function is written in the controller where the color is decided according to the value given.

Could soomeone help me to solve this issue ? Thanks inadvance

Comment: bit unclear, what exactly you wanted to do?

Comment: If the text box is empty users can add values into it, but when the page is loaded the added values need to be displayed and those should be displayed with the relevant  font color. In order to load it with the corrrect color, I should call the function getColor with the value. So the problem here is that I am unable to pass the ng-model value to the ng-class function

Comment: set the default value of color on controller load itself.

Comment: This color changes according to the value. So I guess setting a default color won't work is its already have a value

Answer (score 0):

The above code is correctly work when the relevant css classes are set into the input box as follows.

```
<span class="color">
    <div class="col-value">
         <input type="text" class="input-box"  autofocus="autofocus"  ng-blur="saveData(value)" ng-class="getColor(value)" ng-model="value" >%
    </div>
</span>
```